# current server status information for tomcat7

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, deadlock

I am currently load testing my web application ( Spring + Hibernate based) on a standalone tomcat server (v7.0.27)on a Windows Server 2008 machine. I need to know how tomcat behaves as bulk requests come. e.g.

300 requests recevied - current heap size, server is hung up, server is unable to process, heap size, size of objects, number of objects. So on and so forth.

Is there a way to see this already ? (Info from the manager app is insufficient "current Threads active and memory occupied is not for my requirement).

P.S. maxThreads property for Connector element is 350.

Update : Another issue I faced while load testing - (Tomcat hangs up when i send 300 requests in some cases).

Any help would be highly and greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use jconsole that ships with jdk.
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/management/jconsole.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer.Will try the same and get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

If the server hangs, there might be a deadlock.

You can try to attach with [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), the monitoring section will show you the current locking situation and a possible deadlock.

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.